# How can I create different objects with using one class

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a class and created 3 different objects from it. But when I do a change in one of them, other objects get affected too.

I'm running python on pycharm

```
class Teller():
    def __init__(self,queue=[]):
        self.queue = queue

teller1 = Teller()
teller2 = Teller()
teller1.queue.append(5)
print(teller1.queue)
print(teller2.queue)
```

I expected the results as `[5]` and `[0]`
but instead, I get `[5]` and `[5]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yeah, I have checked that one too, but it was too complicated for me, I didn't understand much. I'm new to python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide default arguments, it uses the same object every time.  So when teller2 is initialized with a default list, it is the **same** list that teller1 got.

A better way to initialize this would be:

```
class Teller():
    def __init__(self,queue=None):
        self.queue = queue if queue else list()
```

Answer (score -1):

Ths is because both your objects point to the same class tat's initialising the same queue. What I guess you could do is create different classes or call different functions.

**Different Functions**

```
class Teller():
    def __init__(self,queue=[]):
        self.queue = queue
    def queue2 (self, queue1=[]):
        self.queue1 = queue1

teller1 = Teller()
teller2 = Teller()
teller1.queue.append(5)
print(teller1.queue)
print(teller2.queue2())
```

**Different Classes**

```
class Teller():
    def __init__(self,queue=[]):
        self.queue = queue

class Teller2():
    def __init__(self, queue = []):
        self.queue = queue

teller1 = Teller()
teller2 = Teller2()
teller1.queue.append(5)
print(teller1.queue)
print(teller2.queue)
```